# show that in the one dimensional case, we have

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

show that in the one dimensional case, we have

$\dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(t,x) = \exp\displaystyle{\left(\int_{t_0}^{t}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(s,\phi(s,x))ds\right)}$.

I tried to solve using the IVP $x'=f(t,x).x \,\,\,\, , x(t_0)=x_0$ and 
I used $\phi$ is a solution. then replace the solution in the IVP and obtain
$\dfrac{\phi '}{\phi}= f(t,\phi)$. From here, I did the integration of $t_0$ to $t$, then partially derived with respect to $x$. In the end I got this relationship

$\dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} = \exp\displaystyle{\left(\int_{t_0}^{t}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(s,\phi(s))ds\right)}$.

I'm finding this question very strange because $\phi$ should not be of the form $\phi (t)$? here we have $\phi(t,x)$ in $\dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(t,x) = \exp\displaystyle{\left(\int_{t_0}^{t}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(s,\phi(s,x))ds\right)}$. Can someone help?

Comment: As introduced $\phi$ is a function of a single variable $t$. What do you mean by writing $\phi(t,x)$ and ${\partial\phi\over\partial x}$? Do you refer to the dependence of $\phi$ on the initial condition $\phi(t_0)=x_0$?

Answer (score 1):

If you are content with purely *formal* calculations, you can proceed as follows.  We have
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}(t, x) = f(t, \phi(t, x)),
$$
which, after differentiating in $x$ and changing order of partials, gives
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Bigl( \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} \Bigr)  (t,x) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t, \phi(t,x))\, \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(t, x).
$$
So, 
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}  (t,x)
$$
(with $x$ for the moment fixed) satisfies a linear ordinary differential equation
$$
y'(t) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t, \phi(t,x))\, y(t).
$$
What about the initial value?  One has $\phi(0, x) = x$, so differentiating it in $x$ we get 
$$
y(0) = 1.
$$
Therefore
$$
\dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(t,x) = \exp\displaystyle{\left(\int_{t_0}^{t}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(s,\phi(s,x))\,ds\right)}.
$$

Indeed, the above calculations are legitimate, since (assuming that $\partial f/\partial x$ is continuous) $\phi(\cdot, \cdot)$ is so regular that one can change the order of partial differentiations, etc. But that's a different story.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!